# Scapy: Adding new protocol with complex field groupings

Tags: python, scapy

I'm trying to specify a new packet format using `scapy`. In the packet there is a list of items, and items consist of "grouped fields". By "grouped fields" I mean a sub-sequence of fields of different types. The only way of making "grouped fields" that I know of in scapy is by using `Packet` class and using `FieldLenField`/`PacketListField` to reference the length of the sequence and the type of list members. Is that the way to go? Something that looks like this:

```
from scapy.packet import Packet
from scapy.fields import *

class RepeatingGroupedSequence(Packet):
    name = "Simple group of two fields"

    fields_desc = [IntField('field1', 1), 
                   IntField('field2', 2)]

class TopLayer(Packet):
    name = "Storage for Repeating Sequence"

    fields_desc = [FieldLenField("length", None, count_of='rep_seq'),
                   PacketListField('rep_seq', None, RepeatingGroupedSequence, 
                                   count_from = lambda pkt: pkt.length),
                  ]

#Now here is the problem that I have with assembling PacketListField: 

#craft TopLayer packet
p = TopLayer()

#add two "repeated sequences"
p.rep_seq = [ RepeatingGroupedSequence(), RepeatingGroupedSequence() ]

#both sequences can observed
p.show()

#but the underlying structure of the repeated sequence is #Raw# at this stage
p.show2()

#length is 2
print p.rep_seq, 'length:', len(p.rep_seq)

#but the cloned packet has only one "repeated sequence", the rest is raw
clone = TopLayer(str(p))
clone.show()

#length is 1
print clone.rep_seq, 'length:', len(clone.rep_seq)
```

The problem with this approach is that the structure of the grouping is not preserved when the packet is reassembled. On assembly, the second instance of the `RepeatedSequence` is treated as a raw body, even though the count field is 2. How do you add `RepeatingSequences` like this so that structure is preserved on reassembly? Is there a way to group Fields without resorting to `Packet` as a storage type for lists?

Comment: If one is using FieldListField() for fields of the same type, the problem does not manifest itself.

Comment: It is also possible to add `Packet` classes directly to the `fields_desc`

Comment: Crazy enough, if `IP` class is used instead of `RepeatingGroupedSequence` everything works!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Class `RepeatingGroupedSequence` needs to overwrite `extract_padding` method:

```
def extract_padding(self, s):
    return '', s
```

By default each sub packet treats everything as belonging to its own layer, ie:

```
def extract_padding(self, s):
    return s, None
```

And this is not what is used for grouping purposes. Can someone elaborate on the difference between padding and layer separation?