# Scapy: Using a PacketListField to dissect multiple packets contained in a packet

Tags: python, packet, scapy, bacnet

I am trying to dissect packets, which encapsulate another packet-like structure, called "tags". The structure looks like this

```
+---------+
|Ether    |
+---------+
|IP       |                   a tag
+---------+
|UDP      |                +------------+
+---------+                |tagNumber   |
|BVLC     |                +------------+
+---------+                |tagClass    |
|NPDU     |                +------------+
+---------+           +-+  |LVT field   |
|APDU     |           |    +------------+
|  +------+--+        |    |            |
|  |Tag 1    | <------+    |  data      |
|  +---------+             |            |
|  |Tag 2    |             +------------+
|  +---------+
|  |Tag n    |
+------------+
```

For this I created a class derived from the existing `PacketListField`, which looks like this:

```
class TagListField(PacketListField):
    def __init__(self):
        PacketListField.__init__(
            self,
            "tags",
            [],
            guessBACNetTagClass,
```

The referenced `guessBACNetTagClass` is a function which returns the correct class needed to dissect the tag.

```
BACNetTagClasses = {
    0x2: "BACNetTag_U_int",
    0xC: "BACNetTag_Object_Identifier"
}

def guessBACNetTagClass(packet, **kargs):

    """ Returns the correct BACNetTag Class needed to dissect
        the current tag

        @type    packet:    binary string
        @param   packet:    the current packet

        @type    cls:       class
        @param   cls:       the correct class for dissection
    """

    tagByteBinary = "{0:b}".format(int(struct.unpack("!B", packet[0])[0]))
    tagNumber = int(tagByteBinary[0:4],2)
    clsName = BACNetTagClasses.get(tagNumber)
    cls = globals()[clsName]
    return cls(packet, **kargs)
```

Currently there are, as you can see from the `BACNetTagClasses` dictionary from above, two of these classes.

```
class BACNetTag_Object_Identifier(Packet):
    name = "BACNetTag_Object_Identifier"
    fields_desc =[
        # fields
    ]

class BACNetTag_U_int(Packet):
    name = "BACNetTag_U_int"
    fields_desc = [
        # fields
    ]
```

In the encapsulating layer, called `APDU` I added the `TagListField` just like another field.

```
class APDU(Packet):

    name = "APDU"
    fields_desc = [
        # Some other fields

        TagListField()
    ]
```

A packet, which I am currently trying to dissect, contains multiple tags. The first one (of the type `BACNetTag_Object_Identifier`) can be correctly dissected, but the remaining tags are just listed as raw payload.

```
[<Ether |<UDP |<BVLC |<NPDU |<APDU 
pduType=UNCONFIRMED_SERVICE_REQUEST reserved=None serviceChoice=I_AM
tags=[<BACNetTag_Object_Identifier  tagNumber=BACNET_OBJECT_IDENTIFIER
tagClass=APPLICATION lengthValueType=4L objectType=DEVICE
instanceNumber=640899L |<Raw  load='"\x01\xe0\x91\x00!\xde'
|>>] |>>>>>>]
```

Is there something wrong with my implementation of `PacketListField`? As I understand, the field should try to dissect the remaining tags until no more Bytes are left.

---

UPDATE:

Using `.show()` reveals a bit more about the packets structure

```
###[ APDU ]###
  pduType   = UNCONFIRMED_SERVICE_REQUEST
  reserved  = None
  serviceChoice= I_AM
  \tags      \
   |###[ BACNetTag_Object_Identifier ]###
   |  tagNumber = BACNET_OBJECT_IDENTIFIER
   |  tagClass  = APPLICATION
   |  lengthValueType= 4L
   |  objectType= DEVICE
   |  instanceNumber= 640899L
   |###[ Raw ]###
   |     load      = '"\x01\xe0\x91\x00!\xde'
```

Scapy just appends the remaining Bytes as a `Raw` layer to the existing `tags` field. That's interesting, but I still don't know why it is doing so.

Comment: Hey, do you know what is the expected parser result for `\x01\xe0\x91\x00!\xde`? Is it another tag? In which case the tagNumber is `0x1` which your code does not support atm? You could make a generic `BACNetTag_Base` which reads all the tags in an content-agnostic way - consume the bytes without identifying the `data` field and make it the default class returned in `guessBACNetTagClass` (which can be extended by `BACNetTag_U_int`). That way all tags (known and unknown) would be parsed. Finally, can this be FCS or similar? Sorry for the too many questions! :)

Comment: I meant return default class if none was identified: `clsName = BACNetTagClasses.get(tagNumber, "BACNetTag_Base")`

Comment: Yes, the expected output are two other tags. Yes, the code here does not support this tag number, but the current version does, yet it still does not work. The generic class is a good idea, I'll try that and update my question. What's FCS?

Comment: [Frame check sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_check_sequence)

Answer (score 4):

Try to overwrite the `extract_padding` method of your `BACNet_Tag*` classes with:

```
def extract_padding(self, s):
return '', s
```

I had similar problems with `PacketListField` and found this stackoverflow post:

[Scapy: Adding new protocol with complex field groupings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073508/scapy-adding-new-protocol-with-complex-field-groupings)